# Fail to update a database table using vb.NET

Tags: database, vb.net

[image]

When I try to update my databse table, what should I do?

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Some [similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+visual+basic+oledbexception+was+unhandled+datatype+mismatch)

Comment: Never concat strings to make SQL.  This is just one of the many many things that can happen.  use SQL Parameters.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0):

it's because mismatched datatype inserted to your columns
change update query to be like this

```
update Hasil_Rml_Hallo_Bro SET Nilai_Error=" & Label3.text & " WHERE ID=" & label4.text
```

remove the "'" apostrophe letter

Answer (score 0):

Always use Parameters

```
Dim query As String = "update Hasil_Rml_Hallo_Bro SET Nilai_Error= @Error WHERE ID=@Id"
Using connection As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
    Using command As New OleDbCommand(query, connection)
        Dim errorParameter As New OleDbParameter With
        {
            .ParameterName = "@Error",
            .OleDbType = OleDbType.VarChar, // Or what is correct type in database
            .Value = Label3.text
        }
        Dim idParameter As New OleDbParameter With
        {
            .ParameterName = "@Id",
            .OleDbType = OleDbType.Integer, // Or what is correct type in database
            .Value = Integer.Parse(label4.text) // Convert to correct type if needed
        }
        command.Parameters.Add(errorParameter, idParameter)

        connection.Open()
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Using
```

Notice that you need put correct type for the parameter  - same as column type you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your column in your database has the same data type which you are inserting into it.